# ApplicationListener invoked twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, events

I'm doing an Spring MVC webapp, then I want to send an email to new registered user in confirm / activation purposes. Then I write an ApplicationEvent and ApplicationListener<> classes. The problem is that, listener is going to invoke twice, so I receive 2 emails, and have 2 token strings in my database.

How to solve this problem?

Code below,

ApplicationEvent:

```
public class OnRegistrationSuccessEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String appUrl;
    private Locale locale;
    private User user;

    public OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(String appUrl, Locale locale, User user) {
        super(user);
        this.appUrl = appUrl;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // getters, setters
}
```

ApplicationListener:

```
@Component
public class RegistrationListener implements ApplicationListener<OnRegistrationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messages;

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event) {
        this.confirmationEmail(event);
    }

    private void confirmationEmail(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event){
       // register token in DB, send mail
    }

    private SimpleMailMessage buildEmailMessage(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event, User user, String token) {
       //build some message
    }
}
```

I invoke the event in @Controller with:

```
eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(URL, request.getLocale(), user));
```

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `publishEvent` is [`ApplicationEventPublisher#publishEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/) with an implementation from one of the built-in `ApplicationContext` subtypes, then it will invoke `onApplicationEvent` only once.

What I think you are experiencing is having multiple `RegistrationListener` objects. An `ApplicationContext` will propagate any events that are published to it to its parent context. I believe you have a `RegistrationListener` bean in each of your root and servlet application contexts. Look at your configuration to figure out how that happened. (You can also log `this` (or something uniquely representative of an instance) within `RegistrationListener` to confirm this.)

> How to solve this problem?

Change your configuration to only produce and register one `Listener` across all your `ApplicationContext`s.